# BeautifulSoup not retrieving elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have tried to extract one div element from a page. i used "class" for that to identify that tag. but it is not detecting the div tag.It is showing an empty list. I am attaching the image of the code below.

[image: It is the code i have used]

Comment: Please, don't post screenshots of code.  It makes it a lot harder to help when you do that.  It won't take that much time to copy in the relevant sections.  Even better, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup.find_all('div',class_='propery card')
```